# Bind buttons to different ViewModels [MVVM]

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have two buttons in one *View*, is it possible to bind one button to one command in first *ViewModel* and another button bind to second command in second *ViewModel*? Just to add both *ViewModels* are initialized.

```
    <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=MainTreeView, Path=DataContext.FirstCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding NameE}">
    <Label Content="{Binding NameE}"/>
 </Button>
  <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=MainTreeView, Path=DataContext.SecondCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding NameD}">
    <Label Content="{Binding NameD}"/>
 </Button>
```

And my two *ViewModels*:

```
public class FirstViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public MyICommand<string> FirstCommand { get; private set; }

     public HomeViewModel()
    {
        FirstCommand = new MyICommand<string>(myFirstCommand);
    }

    public void myFirstCommand(string par)
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
}


public class SecondViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public MyICommand<string> SecondCommand { get; private set; }

     public HomeViewModel()
    {
        SecondCommand = new MyICommand<string>(mySecondCommand);
    }

    public void mySecondCommand(string par)
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
}
```

EDIT: In a view where are buttons i have `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}"/>` and that Content have *View* with a *ViewModel* i wanna reach with buttons

Comment: depends on how view and view models are wired together

Comment: In a view where are buttons i have `<ContentPresenter  Content="{Binding Content}"/>` and that Content have View with a _ViewModel_ i wanna reach with buttons.

Comment: Have you considered making the two ViewModels properties of a parent ViewModel and then linking to them through this?

Comment: I didn't, i will look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most generic solution is to make your view models globally accessible by instantiating them in the App.xaml `ResourceDictionary`:

App.xaml:

```
<Application ...>
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <FirstViewModel x:Key="FirstViewModel" />
      <SecondViewModel x:Key="SecondViewModel" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

or using C# (e.g., App.xaml.cs)

```
Application.Current.Resources.Add("FirstViewModel", new FirstViewModel(arg1, arg2));
Application.Current.Resources.Add("SecondViewModel", new SecondViewModel(arg1, arg2));
```

Now you can reference them from any view:

```
<Button Content="{Binding NameE}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding NameE}" 
        Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource FirstViewModel}, Path=FirstCommand}" />

<Button Content="{Binding NameD}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding NameD}" 
        Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource SecondViewModel}, Path=SecondCommand}" />
```

---

Another solution is to use composition and wrap the view models into a parent view model:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public FirstViewModel FirstViewModel { get; private set; }
  public SecondViewModel SecondViewModel { get; private set; }

  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this.FirstViewModel = new FirstViewModel();
    this.SecondViewModel = new SecondViewModel();
  }
}

public class FirstViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public MyICommand<string> FirstCommand { get; private set; }

  public FirstViewModel()
  {
    FirstCommand = new MyICommand<string>(myFirstCommand);
  }

  public void myFirstCommand(string par)
  {
    Console.Beep();
  }
}


public class SecondViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public MyICommand<string> SecondCommand { get; private set; }

  public SecondViewModel()
  {
    SecondCommand = new MyICommand<string>(mySecondCommand);
  }

  public void mySecondCommand(string par)
  {
    Console.Beep();
  }
}
```

Usage

```
<TreeView x:Name="MainTreeView">
  <TreeView.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel />
  </TreeView.DataContext>
</TreeView>


<Button Content="{Binding NameE}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding NameE}" 
        Command="{Binding ElementName=MainTreeView, Path=DataContext.FirstViewModel.FirstCommand}" />

<Button Content="{Binding NameD}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding NameD}" 
        Command="{Binding ElementName=MainTreeView, Path=DataContext.SecondViewModel.SecondCommand}" />
```

Comment: Can you put code how do I instants them in the App.xaml?

Comment: It was just hidden because I forgot to indent the code.

Comment: such approach has very limited use. very often multiple instances of view model type are required. and almost always view model doesn't have a constructor without parameters, required for xaml - view models usually needs a model and some services

Comment: @ASh Of course, I know. That's why I said it's the _"easiest and most generic solution"_. There are no more details on his data context or application structure or class details (except the parameterless constructor). But you can always add shared instances (that require constructor parameters e.g., in an advanced scenario that utilizes Dependency Injection) to the app resources using C# like `Application.Current.Resources.Add("FirstViewModel", new FirstViewModel(arg1, arg2));`.